Parametric Equation of a unit circle when the angle between $x$-axis and $y$-axis is not $90$ degrees
I know in regular Cartesian coordinates the parametric equation for a unit circle is $x=\cos(\theta)$, $y=\sin(\theta)$, and if the $x$ coordinates are stretched by an amount $a$, and the $y$ coordinates are stretched by an amount $b$ while the angle between the $x$ and $y$ coordinates is still $90$ degrees then the distance formula becomes $ds^2=a^2dx^2+b^2dy^2$ and so the equation for a unit circle becomes $a^2x^2+b^2y^2=1$, and the parametric equation of the unit circle becomes $x=\frac{\cos(\theta)}{a}$, $y=\frac{\sin(\theta)}{b}$ because $a^2\frac{\cos^2(\theta)}{a^2}+b^2\frac{\sin^2(\theta)}{b^2}=\cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta)=1$, and I’m not sure what the parametric equation for a unit circle would be in this case.
If the angle between the $x$-axis and $y$-axis is not $90$ degrees then the distance formula becomes $ds^2=a^2dx^2+2abdxdy\cos(\psi)+b^2dy^2$ with $\psi$ being the angle between the $x$-axis and the $y$-axis.  This means that the equation of a unit circle becomes $a^2x^2+2abxy\cos(\psi)+b^2y^2=1$, and from this I don’t know what the parametric equation of a unit circle would be.  I mean given a parametric equation I know how to test to see if it’s a valid equation for a unit circle but I don’t know how to derive the equation for a unit circle in this case.
Also some other criteria I have in this case is that while $\psi$ is not necessarily $90$ degrees it has a constant value everywhere, and while $a$, and $b$ are not necessarily $1$ they also have constant values everywhere as well.  Also if there are two segments of the circle of the same arc lengths the change in $\theta$ needs to be the same for both segments of the circle.

Start with the standard parameterization and perform a coordinate transformation.

Let's consider a non orthogonal Cartesian reference system with unit vectors of the axes $\textbf{e}_1,\textbf{e}_2$, with $|\textbf{e}_1|=|\textbf{e}_1|=1$ and $\textbf{e}_1\cdot\textbf{e}_2=\cos\theta$.
The equation of the unit circle can be written as $|P-O|^2=1$ where $O=(0,0)$ is the origin of the reference system, while $P = (x,y)$
so that
$$
P-O = x\,\textbf{e}_1+y\,\textbf{e}_2
$$
Given that
$$
|P-O|^2 = |x\,\textbf{e}_1+y\,\textbf{e}_2|^2 = x^2+y^2+2xy\cos\theta
$$
the circle equation is
$$
x^2+y^2+2xy\cos\theta = 1
$$
Let's consider now a change of variable, in particular a rotation of an angle $\alpha$:
\begin{align}
x &= \xi\cos\alpha - \eta\sin\alpha, \\
y &= \xi\sin\alpha + \eta\cos\alpha, \\
\end{align}
Substituting into the circle equation we have
$$
\xi^2(1+2\cos\theta\sin\alpha\cos\alpha)+\eta^2(1-2\cos\theta\sin\alpha\cos\alpha)+2\xi\eta\cos\theta(\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha)=1
$$
To have an canonical ellipsis equation, without the $\xi\eta$ term, we should require
$$
\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha=\cos(2\alpha) = 0 \implies \alpha=\pi/4
$$
With this choice, the equation becomes
$$
\xi^2(1+\cos\theta)+\eta^2(1-\cos\theta)=1
$$
that can be parametrized as
\begin{align}
\xi  &= \frac{\cos t}{\sqrt{1+\cos\theta}}, \\
\eta &= \frac{\sin t}{\sqrt{1-\cos\theta}}
\end{align}
Turnin back to our original coordinates $x,y$, we have
\begin{align}
x &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\frac{\cos t}{\sqrt{1+\cos\theta}}-\frac{\sin t}{\sqrt{1-\cos\theta}}\right), \\
y &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\frac{\cos t}{\sqrt{1+\cos\theta}}+\frac{\sin t}{\sqrt{1-\cos\theta}}\right)
\end{align}

I tried the above equation and found that it doesn’t seem to work as it doesn’t always give values of 1 when I use the metric on it to find the distance from the origin.  Also it doesn’t seem to reduce to $x=\cos{t}$, $y=\sin{t}$ when $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$

@AndersGustafson, it reduces to
$
\left(\frac{\cos t-\sin t}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{\cos t+\sin t}{\sqrt{2}}\right) = \left(\cos\left(t+\frac{\pi}{4}\right),\sin\left(t+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right)=(\cos t', \sin t')
$
with $t' = t+\pi/4$.
As to regard to the metric, I don't exactly understand you issue, can you clarify?

Well I tried generating random values of $t$ and $\theta$, using your formula to get the values of $x$, and $y$.  Then I used the formula $r^2=x^2+2xy\cos{\theta}+y^2$ to calculate the distance to the origin and found that I got distances too far from $1$ to be explained away as a rounding error, such as $3$ point something, negative numbers, and some other non $1$ values.

@AndersGustafson you are doing something wrong, because direct calculations give exactly 1
